# how to extend Request type in Express with custom property

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to set up a custom middleware function in Node.js with typescript, where I want to store a decoded json web token into a custom request property 'user' like this

```
  function auth(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {

     const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, config.get("secret"));

     req.user = decodedToken.user; 
     next();
  }
```

but I keep getting a compiler error in the terminal

> error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.

I found several answers on here that suggested creating a custom.d.ts file and extend the Request type which I did like this:

```
namespace Express {
  interface Request {
    user?: string;
  }
}
```

now, the VS Code is happy, I get no linting, I get the correct intellisense and autocompletion and it does not let me assign a number, because it understands it needs to be a string. So it obviously works. However, when I run the code the terminal keeps giving me the same error and insists that property 'user' does not exist.

I tried restarting the TS server but that did not help.

I can make it work by creating a custom interface which extends the Request type and then using that, but I really want to know how to do it with the original Request type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work after a lot of googling and playing with folder structure and *tsconfig.json* file. I put the `custom.d.ts` file in `./@types/express` (the sub-folder has to be there) and set the typeRoots in *tsconfig.json* like this:

```
compilerOptions: {
  "typeRoots": ["./@types"],
}
```

I also had to declare the namespace in custom.d.ts

```
declare namespace Express {
  interface Request {
    user: any;
  }
}
```

Now it compiles without error

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do it on the original object with typescript - that's coming from Express and you're importing it from Express. The best you can do there is extend it like you have, or ignore the errors.

You definitely *can* do it in theory - you can add whatever you want to the `req` object in a middleware because it's just that - a javascript object. The warning you're getting is from typescript, not Express.

In practice, what you'd normally do is use `res.locals` for something like this. In typescript, it's defined as `locals: Record<string, any>`. So you could set `res.locals.user` in your middleware and then access it later wherever you want.

Comment: thanks, res.locals is working fine, I guess I will stick with that. What I cannot understand is why typescript is giving the error because it clearly recognizes the custom property from the extended interface

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding this quite right, but, I think that the best solution is to create a custom Request class, adding this property.

```
export class CRequest extends Request {
    user?: string
    //add stuff to constructor etc
}
```

Now, you want to make it an interface, just replace class with interface
I also do not reccomend you use the same name as Express & Request

Comment: thanks for the reply. I think what I'm trying to understand here is why typescript gives error when I try to compile it, when it can clearly see the custom property while I'm writing the code